# Details of group with ID less than 500

Tags: linux, shell, sh, redhat

I want to list the group details (available in /etc/groups) with group ID less than 500 and greater than 500. Can anyone provide me a good shell command to get this details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "group details"? Standard /etc/group has no comment field.

Comment: "less than 500 and greater than 500" is the same as "not equal to 500". So: `awk -F: '$3!=500' /etc/group`

Answer (score -1):

As with any other text file, you can use `egrep` by providing a regex which will filter out unwanted records, for example you can use the following expression:

```
egrep ".:[1-4]?[0-9]?[0-9].|.:5[0-9][1-9]." /etc/group
```

Comment: won't that match every line? You might need more colons